# opening a file in its native program with GWT

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I wanted to **open the files** available in my web application to its corresponding **native apps in PC**. I have created the set of program to download the file from web app but didn't know how to set that files to open with native app in system. kindly help me in this. If you have any other options to use rather than downloading and displaying the file please suggest me.

**Note:** I am using eclipse to develop web app

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not related to GWT. Just provide links to files in your app. When a user clicks on link, user's browser/PC will decide what to do with a file. It will either open the file within a browser (PDF, images, some video and music files depending on a browser), or it will offer to save them.